# I've found a minor problem on my output! can anyone say what's going on my code?

Tags: java, palindrome

> This is my function

```
public static String  isPalindrome(String str) {
    String test = "";
    String anotherStirng="";
    for (int i = str.length()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        test = test + str.charAt(i);
    }
    return anotherStirng = (str.equals(test) ? "yes" : "no");

}
```

> main is here ...

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int numberOfInput = scanner.nextInt();
    String str ="";
    String result="";
    for (int i=0;i<numberOfInput;i++){
            str = scanner.nextLine();
            result = isPalindrome(str);
            System.out.println(result);
```

**when i enter number of input in the console like 3 or 4, it automatically say "yes" after that its works fine**

Comment: This sounds like a scanner problem, not any other issue with your code.  The first call to `Scanner#nextInt()` seems to become an input into the palindrome method.  After this, all works as expected.

Comment: Replace `int numberOfInput = scanner.nextInt();` with `int numberOfInput = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());`

Comment: nextInt doesn't go to the next line ... you have to call nextLine again before teh for loop starts

Comment: `nextInt` doesn't consume the newline character, so the first call to `nextLine` returns the empty string, which is indeed a palindrome. Instead of calling `nextInt`, try `int numberOfInputs = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine().strip());`

Comment: #forpas, you are awesome!it now works perfectly

Answer (score 3):

You forgot "scanner.nextLine();" in your code after reading int value.
Explanation why you need this line is [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo)

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int numberOfInput = scanner.nextInt();
    scanner.nextLine();   // ADDED LINE
    String str ="";
    String result="";
    for (int i=0;i<numberOfInput;i++){
            str = scanner.nextLine();
            result = isPalindrome(str);
            System.out.println(result);
    }
```